# Are all non-computable functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ denumerable?

Tags: functions, logic, recursion, computability

In the Cutland book called Computability, there is a very interesting exercise on page 81.

> **Show that the set of all non-computable total functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is not denumerable.**

I have already shown that the set of all computable functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is denumerable. But i have not yet shown that the set of all total functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is uncontable.

Thanks!

I want to ask another question related to this. I have developed the next conjecture.

> **CONJECTURE: The set of all partial functions $f:(0,n)\rightarrow (0,n)$, being n a finite natural number, are computable, and the cardinality of this set is $n^n$ (finite).**

I think that there are no NON-computable functions $f:(0,n)\rightarrow (0,n)$ because the set is finite. Could you please tell me if this is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know the set of total functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ is uncountable (not denumerable)?

Comment: I also want to show that the set of total functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

Comment: Then do you know the power set of $\mathbb N$ is uncountable?

Comment: Yes, I know that...

Comment: Then $2^{\mathbb N}\leq\mathbb N^\mathbb N$, which implies the latter is uncountable.

Comment: But, I believe that $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is de cardinality of the set of all total functions. Could the cardinality of **non-computable** functions be $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} - \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: yes, so $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} - \mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

Comment: Excuse me but i want to understand very well this subject. $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} - \mathbb{N}$ is an expression of the form $\infty - \infty$. This is an indetermination, isn't it?

Comment: Assume $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} - \mathbb{N}$ is countable, then  $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} = (\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} - \mathbb{N}) \cup \mathbb{N}$. Since unions of countable set is countable, this implies $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is countable, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Carlos No - just because you can suggestively write a nonsensical expression which looks similar, doesn't mean that the actual object in question is at all problematic. Analogously (although quite different in topic): $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{x\over x}$ makes perfect sense, even though $0\over 0$ is meaningless.

Comment: Also, rather than add a new aspect to an already-answered question, you should just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the set ${\Bbb N}^{\Bbb N}$ is not denumerable (use Cantor's second diagonal argument to show this), while the set of all computable functions ${\Bbb N}\rightarrow{\Bbb N}$ is denumerable (the set of all Turing/Goto/Registermachine programs or the set of all C-programs over a finite alphabet is denumerable).